# Can Arduino Uno code run on a BeagleBone Black using a cross compiler?

Tags: java, c++, arduino, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I am currently part of a research team that is developing an unmanned submarine for local rescue divers. The goal is to improve and fix the prototype from last year's team.

Right now the vehicle uses an Arduino Uno and a BeagleBone Black. The Arduino controls six rotors and a few on-board sensors, while the BeagleBone controls an on-board camera (don't ask why, this setup was chosen. The previous team is long gone, so we have no choice but to move forward).

According to the last team, the Arduino couldn't control all of the equipment due to "shield" issues. Using the BeagleBone for everything would've been optimal, but the team couldn't rewrite the code in 2 days (no one knew Java). Since I only know Java, my initial plan for the course of the project was to learn C++ and rewrite the code in Java.

Recently, I came across the term "cross compiler" which, from what I understood, allowed a program, written in one language, to run on a platform that uses a different language. Would a cross-compiler be able to take code from an Arduino and "convert" it for BeagleBone? It seems like the code would be too complex to be converted from language to language. Sorry if I sound "noobish" I'm a mechanical engineer student who took one Java class.

Comment: Your question is not a problem with a code or so, and will be considered a general question that should be searched in a different forum. I suggest you show us what you have searched and tried

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to compile the C/C++ code from the Arduino on the BeagleBone but it wouldn't work the same way.  The I/O ports are not going to be addressed the same way and there are likely many other issues.  On the Arduino your program is pretty much the only thing running.  On a BeagleBone you've got a full fledged Unix O/S running and your code is one of many processes.

If you know Java the C/C++ code shouldn't be too hard to read.  Reading the ports and controlling what I would guess would be servos is certainly possible on the BeagleBone.  If you've got some Auduino shields though that could be an issue.  They may talk SPI or I2C but they may instead use something lower level - maybe just a PWM signal.

This isn't going to be a trivial project but my opinion is that you're heading the right way.  I'd take one subsystem at a time and re-write that code for the BeagleBone.  Something like this [cape](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Motor-Bridge-Cape-p-2569.html) can drive steppers or servos.  However, that brings up another problem - the supplied [library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/MotorBridgeCapeforBBG_BBB) is in Python - yet some more porting to be done.

So cross-compilation won't help - the code is theoretically portable but not really.  It's going to take a rewrite.

Comment: Thanks st! I expected there would be the issue. I'm not familiar with the hardware expansion shields. In what way would shields cause a problem?

Comment: If you're dependent on a particular Arduino shield it may not be available as a cape for BeagleBone.  If you're doing "standard" stuff like steppers/servos/PWM and serial i/o you'll be fine but talking to the shield/cape will be different between Arduino and BeagleBone.